# Expression for $\exp \left(\frac{1}{1-z} \right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for $|z|<1$, we have

$$\exp \left(\frac{1}{1-z} \right)=e+ez+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(k+2)\cdots(k+n)}{k!} z^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the binomial theorem,
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-k}{n}(-z)^n\ .$$
Now
$$\eqalign{\binom{-k}{n}
  &=\frac{(-k)(-k-1)\cdots(-k-(n-1))}{n!}\cr
  &=(-1)^n\frac{k(k+1)\cdots(k+n-1)}{n!}\cr}$$
and so
$$\eqalign{\frac{1}{(1-z)^k}
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)\cdots(k+n-1)}{n!}z^n\cr
  &=1+kz+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)\cdots(k+n-1)}{n!}z^n\ .\cr}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{\exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{1-z}\Bigr)
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(1-z)^k}\cr
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{kz}{k!}
    +\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}
     \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)\cdots(k+n-1)}{k!}z^n\ .\cr}$$
You should immediately recognise the first sum as $e$, and it's not hard to show that the second is $ez$.  For the third, note that the term with $k=0$ is zero and we may therefore start the sum at $k=1$; then substitute $k+1$ instead of $k$.

See if you can finish the details.

Comment: Okay!, I did the same, I think it was the most expected way of doing exercises. regards

Answer (score 0):

By the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties for the Bell polynomials of the second kind, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\biggl[\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr)\biggr]^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp^{(k)}\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr)B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{1!}{(1-z)^2},\frac{2!}{(1-z)^3},\dotsc, \frac{(n-k+1)!}{(1-z)^{n-k+2}}\biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr) \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+k}} B_{n,k}(1!,2!,\dotsc,(n-k+1)!)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr) \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+k}} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}\\
&\to n!e\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}
\end{align*}
as $z\to0$, where $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc, x_{n-k+1})$ denotes the Bell polynomials of the second kind. Consequently, we acquire
\begin{equation*}
\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr)=e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}\Biggr]z^n, \quad z\in[-1,1).
\end{equation*}

By the above method, we obtained
\begin{equation*}
\sin\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin\biggl(1+\frac{k\pi}{2}\biggr) \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}\Biggr]z^n, \quad z\in[-1,1).
\end{equation*}
at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253870.

Note that the Faa di Bruno formula, the Bell polynomials of the second kind, and their proprties and identies can be found in the following references.

References

1. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
2. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
3. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterranean Journal of Mathematics **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.