# Taylor coefficient of $f(z)=\exp\left\{\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to figure out the Taylor coefficient of $\exp\left\{\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right\}$. My idea is as follows:
$$f(z)=\exp\left\{\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right\}=\exp\left\{1+\frac{2}{z-1}\right\}=e\exp\left\{\frac{2}{z-1}\right\}.$$
Then we have $f(z)=e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{w^n}{n!}$, where $w=\frac{2}{z-1}$. Clearly, we have
$$w^n=(-2)^n(1-z)^{-n}=(-2)^n\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{k!\Gamma(n)}z^k.$$
It follows that
$$f(z)=e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{w^n}{n!}=e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{k!\Gamma(n)}z^k=e\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{k!\Gamma(n)}z^k.$$
Namely, the $n$-th coefficient of $f$ is given by
$$\widehat{f}(k)=e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{k!\Gamma(n)}.$$
I have checked that $\widehat{f}(0)=f(0)$ and $\widehat{f}(1)=f'(0)$. Moreover, the fact that $f''(0)=0$  implies that $\widehat{f}(2)$ should be zero. But in our result it seems that
$$\widehat{f}(2)=e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{2!\Gamma(n)}\neq 0.$$
What is wrong with my formula? Could you help me figure our the problem and tfind out the Taylor coefficient of the $f$? Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't $\exp\left\{1+\frac{2}{z+1}\right\}$ be $\exp\left\{1+\frac{2}{z-1}\right\}$ instead?

Comment: another way to do it is to use that $f'=-\frac{2}{(z-1)^2}f$ which gives a recurrence for the coefficients - useful especially if you want to do only a few of them

Comment: @DMcMor Thank you for pointing out my typin error.

Comment: @ Conrad Good idea! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$ f(z):=\exp{\big(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\big)} =\frac{1}{e}\exp{\big(\frac{2z}{z-1}\big)} $$
Use the generating function for the Laguerre polynomials to show
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{e} \sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n^{(-1)}(2)z^n $$
Thus, using the 'coefficient of' operator
$$ [z^n] f(z) = \frac{1}{e} L_n^{(-1)}(2) .$$
It is perhaps more convenient to look up the explicit construction of the Laguerre polynomial and write this as
$$ [z^n] f(z) = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^m\binom{n-1}{n-m}\frac{2^m}{m!} .$$

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate the coefficients $a_n$ of
$$f(z)=\exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)=\frac 1e\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \,z^n$$ using the reccurence formula

$$a_n=\frac{n-2}n\,({2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}}) \quad \text{with} \quad a_0=1 \quad \text{and} \quad a_1=- 2 $$

Answer (score 0):

By the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties for the Bell polynomials of the second kind, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\biggl[\exp\biggl(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\biggr)\biggr]^{(n)}
&=e\biggl[\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{z-1}\biggr)\biggr]^{(n)}\\
&\hskip-8em=e\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp^{(k)}\biggl(\frac{1}{z-1}\biggr)B_{n,k}\biggl((-1)^1\frac{1!}{(z-1)^2},(-1)^2\frac{2!}{(z-1)^3},\dotsc, (-1)^{n-k+1}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{(z-1)^{n-k+2}}\biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{z-1}\biggr) \frac{(-1)^n}{(z-1)^{n+k}} B_{n,k}(1!,2!,\dotsc,(n-k+1)!)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{z-1}\biggr) \frac{(-1)^n}{(z-1)^{n+k}} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}\\
&\to \frac{n!}{e}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we acquire
\begin{equation*}
\exp\biggl(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\biggr)
=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}\biggr]z^n.
\end{equation*}

References

1. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4700985
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253870
4. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
5. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4701007