# Taylor coefficients of $\exp⁡(1/(1-z))$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm specifically interested in estimating the growth of the coefficients $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the Taylor series of $$\exp⁡(1/(1-z))$$ centered in $0$: knowing that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow+\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=1$, what I'm trying to figure out is whether the growth of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is at most polynomial or super-polynomial... I tried to calculate explicitly the coefficients in order to find some regularity in the sequence of the coefficients, but I quickly got lost in the process.

Thanks in advance for any answer or suggestion.

Comment: According to WA, (see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+exp(1%2F(1-x))), the Taylor expansion is $$e^{1/(1-z)}= e \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A_n}{n!} z^n$$ where $A_n$ is the sequence https://oeis.org/A000262 . Hope it helps.

Comment: According to the link you've reported, it seems that A(n) ~ n^(n-1/4)*exp(-1/2+2*sqrt(n)-n)/sqrt(2) * (1 - 5/(48*sqrt(n)) - 95/(4608*n)). So, using Stirling formula, we get that $a_n$ is asymptotic to something minorated by $ \frac{C}{n}e^{2\sqrt{n}}$, showing that the growth is superpolynomial... just a question: is that source reliable? I haven't found there how they proved that result... i'm a little puzzled, because i don't get the reason why in this espression appears the term (1 - 5/(48*sqrt(n)) - 95/(4608*n)): being an asymptotic statement, it seems pretty useless...

Comment: The asymptotic formula is signed  Karol A. Penson, and one of the links is a paper with co-author  K. A. Penson, so I would guess that is a place to look.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126698/coefficient-growth-in-the-power-series-sum-u-n-zn-e1-1-z

Comment: At https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4700985/945479, there is a nice answer to this question:
\begin{equation*}
\exp\biggl(\frac{1}{1-z}\biggr)=e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}\Biggr]z^n, \quad z\in[-1,1).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick proof of the leading asymptotic term.  Use the associated Laguerre polynomial generating function (Gradshteyn 8.975.1) to determine that 
$$e^{-1}e^{1/(1-z)} = e^{z/(1-z)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n^{-1}(-1)z^n.$$
Use a contour integral representation of the Laguerre polynomials to show that
$$L_n^{-1}(-1)=\frac{1}{n\,2\pi\,i}  \oint (1+1/t)^n\,e^t\,dt.$$
The contour will be deformed through the saddle point which occurs at $t_0=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{4n+1}).$  Saddle point analysis yields the approximation
$$L_n^{-1}(-1) \sim \exp{(2\sqrt{n} -1/2)}\, \frac{1}{n\,2\pi\,i}\lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{-ia}^{ia} \exp{(c(t-t_o)^2)}\,dt.$$
In this formula the leading exponential is the asymptotic expansion for $n \to \infty$ of $(1+1/t_0)^n\,e^{t_0}.$  The $c$ in the equation, again keeping only the largest term, is $c=1/\sqrt{n}.$A rigorous application of saddle point method will show that value of all but that on a vertical line segment can be neglected, and that segment can be extended to $\infty$ with negligible affect, and the integral becomes the well-known Gaussian. Collecting results we find that 
$$L_n^{-1}(-1) \sim  \frac{\exp{(2\sqrt{n} -1/2)}}{ 2\sqrt{\pi} \, n^{3/4} } $$
It is interesting that a naive first attempt argued as follows:
$$L_n^{-1}(-1) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n \binom{n}{m} \frac{m}{m!} \sim 
\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{n^m}{m!} \frac{m}{m!} \sim \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{n^m}{m!} \frac{m}{m!}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\,I_1(2\sqrt{n}).$$  One can use the known asymptotics of the Bessel function and get an expansion that agrees with the above $\textit{except for a factor of }$ $\exp{(-1/2)}.$ I thought that $\binom{n}{m} \sim n^m/m!$ would certainly work since the weight of $1/(m-1)!$ heavily emphasizes the beginning terms of the sum.  Numerical evidence shows that it wasn't.  I should've remembered that the approximation assumes fixed $m$, but there is a summation so $m$ can get quite large. It's interesting that a mistake only ended up with a different constant before the asymptotic expression.

Answer (score 1):

A simple calculation (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021175/expression-for-exp-left-frac11-z-right) question) yields$$ \exp \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n!} \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k)_n}{k!}\right) z^n $$
with the Pochhammer symbol $(k)_n = k (k+1) \cdots (k + n - 1)$ .

Mathematica manages to evaluate the sum over $k$ in terms of the confluent hypergeometric function:
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k)_n}{k!} = {_1}F_1 (n+1;2;1) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)_k}{(2)_k k!} \, , \, n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \, . $$
I have no idea how to derive this result, since the partial sums do not even agree, but it seems accurate numerically.

The asymptotic behaviour of the hypergeometric function is documented [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.8#iii) (equation 13.8.12; $_1 F_1$ is called $M$) and the leading order term yields
$$ a_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{e}}{4 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2 \sqrt{n}}}{n^{3/4}} \, , n \rightarrow \infty \, ,$$
so the growth is indeed superpolynomial.